# Data binding in Angular 4 with 3rd party component

Tags: angular

I am using 3rd party, but I belive that it is not a problem with it, but with my code.

I used the datepicker from:

```
https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker
```

And then packed it into directive:

```
import { IMyDpOptions, IMyMonthLabels, IMyDate, IMyDateRange } from 'mydatepicker';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output, } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datepicker',
  template:
  `<my-date-picker name="mydate"  [(ngModel)]="model" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)" ></my-date-picker>`
})
export class DatePicker implements OnInit {

  public model: any;


  @Input('Date') DateString: string;
  @Output('DateChange') DateChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.model = { date: { year: 1999, month: 12, day: 12 } };
  }


  public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    // other options...
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy',

  };

  onDateChanged(event: any) {
    let date = event.date.year + "-" + event.date.month + "-" + event.date.day;
    this.DateChange.emit(date);

  }

}
```

https://angular-y5ephz.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5ephz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

And the problem is that second datepicker does not change its value, although its value is being changed in the getDay method.

The question is, how to force second  to change its value...

Comment: Please post some more code; show the code where you call the DatePicker?

Comment: I added link to the code

Answer (score 0):

Your component is emitting the value correctly to the function `getDay($event)`.
But in that function your setting both dates: 
`this.date1 = this.date2 = event;`

Try this: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrwigv?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: You have missunderstood.

I want to change both values in datepickers when date in the first one (upper) was changed

Comment: So when I click on the first input and select for example date: 2012-12-12, the same date should appear in the second datepicker input.